# Trying to install *.apk throws ParseError

Tags: android, cordova

I can install my **-unaligned.apk on my device.
But I cannot install my releaseable apk. I get:

> ParseError: Parsing the package...

How can this be?

How do I build my app:

```
call cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device 
call cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen

call cordova platform add android 
call cordova build android call cordova build android --release

call jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my.keystore -storepass **** platforms/android/ant-build/MainActivity-release-unsigned.apk myalias 

call jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs platforms/android/ant-build/MainActivity-release-unsigned.apk zipalign
    -v 4 platforms/android/ant-build/MainActivity-release-unsigned.apk release.apk
```

my config.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.myapp.test" version="2.0.1">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <author>Me</author>

<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/2.0/globalization"/>
<content src="index.html"/>
<access origin="*"/> 


<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17" />

<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />

<platform name="android">
    <splash src="android/splash/land/hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="android/splash/land/hdpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="android/splash/land/hdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="android/splash/land/hdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="android/splash/port/hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="android/splash/port/ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="android/splash/port/mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="android/splash/port/xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>

    <icon src="android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
</platform>
```

The generated AndroidManifest.xml has the targetSdk=21. This is android 5.0.1.. My device is Android 5.0. Can I specify the targetSdk in my config.xml?

Comment: is anyone of your file name starts with _(underscore), want to check that http://stackoverflow.com/a/22618261/1225413

Comment: No. I can install the *unaligned.apk. The problem is with the zipaligned one.

Answer (score 0):

In your config.xml, you will find the package name. Note it down and while `zipalign`, use that package name instead of **release**.apk. Let me know if this won't work.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. I add my config.xml and run the build with com.myapp.test.apk but did not work.

Comment: But I see a point: My device is Android 5.0... The targetSDK ist in the AndroidManifest.xml API 21, which is Android 5.0.1... Can this be the problem? But I think than I could not install the unaligned.apk too...