# Disabling AutoHideSplashScreen for Android not working

Tags: android, cordova

The following Phonegap project (Phonegap Build) is not working:

config.xml:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
```

Index:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

window.location = 'http://www.example.com/login';

 document.AddEventListener("deviceready", OnDeviceReady, false);

    function OnDeviceReady() {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }, 6000);
    };

   </script>
  </head>
```

The splash screen stays all the time and loads. The redirecting to the homepage is not working.

I tried this:
[PhoneGap Build iOS app has blank white screen after splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339647/phonegap-build-ios-app-has-blank-white-screen-after-splash-screen)

this:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/splash_screen_autohidesplashscreen_false_not_working_iphone_ios7 (Version 0.2.3 of Plugin)

Nothing is working. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The splashscreen plugin does not support `AutoHideSplashScreen` for Android. See also this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8396.

As for the redirect not working, try `window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/login';`

Comment: it's now supported from v3.2.0

Answer (score 3):

Fast forward to 2016: This was just recently implemented. You need `cordova-plugin-splashscreen@3.2.0` (released Feb 2016)

See https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/pull/74

Answer (score -1):

If you want disable the splashscreen, you should add `onDeviceReady` in the body of http://www.example.com/login

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10233538)

Comment: @LawrenceAiello This isn't a link-only answer. example.com isn't a real site.