# Cordova - white screen after splash, no exceptions in console

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I've been away from my Cordova app for a bit, but just did a fresh clone yesterday and noticed that it's got the "white screen of death" symptoms -- the splash screen displays, the program loads... and then I just get a blank screen. Some more details:

- CLI: Cordova 6.1.1, android 5.1.1, ios 4.1.1
- I'm not using any special plugins to display a splash screen -- just `<splash>` elements in [my config.xml file](https://github.com/adapt-it/adapt-it-mobile/blob/master/www/config.xml).
- This is happening in both iOS and Android, both on local builds and using PhoneGap Build (i.e., debug and release).
- There are no exceptions of missing resources in the console, either in iOS (using Safari's dev tools) or Android (using Chrome's dev tools).
- I've done a [diff with my last known working build](https://github.com/adapt-it/adapt-it-mobile/compare/65b70a3e782f82c6e05c21e687f2b7987889e320...master), and there's really nothing that pops out. I saw an undefined Underscore reference, but I backed that change out and it didn't resolve anything -- I think I'd see the exception in the console, anyway.

Has Cordova / PhoneGap done something recently that might be causing this? Any ideas on how to isolate this one? I'm really stumped.

Comment: If it's failing on both, you probably have some problem on your code

Comment: Did you get any error while building or updating the project?
Did you try the removing the platform and adding again?
Your project is working proper for me when i added the iOS platform and run it in Cordova 6.1.1 and iOS 4.1.1 versions

Comment: @Pyro: Thanks, I managed to find the problem last night -- a breaking API change in the SQLite plugin threw an exception. Unfortunately it didn't show up in the Chrome / Safari dev tools, but it did throw in the browser target. Go figure.

Comment: ok , that's great, also, you have maintained the great quality level in code, i will able to learn something from that

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well that was ugly. It turned out that there *was* an exception being thrown, it was just being thrown too early for the browser dev tools to pick it up (Safari, Chrome for iOS and Android, respectively). The exception did show up when I ran things through the browser target (`cordova platform add browser`, etc.) So that browser platform is useful for something I guess. :-)

In my case, the cordova-sqlite-storage plugin had made a breaking API change that broke the code when I updated everything. The solution was to pin the plugin to an earlier version in the config.xml file.

So, lessons learned:

- If you suspect there's an exception being thrown during startup, you can use the browser platform to track it down.
- Pin your plugins to a specific version using the `spec` parameter in the config.xml. This will save you some heartache in the future.
- [another option from @jcesarmobile, below] hitting refresh in the browser dev tools will also kick out the exception. Nice!

I'll be going back in to the config.xml and pinning the other items -- and doing some cleanup as suggested above. Thanks again, everyone.

Comment: in a situation like this, the 'console plugin' for Cordova may be useful, as for the iOS it displays the log in the Xcode console if the project is run from Xcode, which may help in detecting this type of issue link:https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console

Comment: Safari remote web inspector have a reload button that should catch that kind of errors

Answer (score 7):

I manged to run your app this are the steps I followed.

1) First you need to declare Splash screen preference along with splash screen plugin location in your **config.xml**. This is what I think you are missing

```
<preference
    name="SplashScreen"
    value="screen" />
<preference
    name="AutoHideSplashScreen"
    value="true" />
<preference
    name="SplashScreenDelay"
    value="5000" />

<feature name="SplashScreen" >
    <param
        name="android-package"
        value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />

    <param
        name="onload"
        value="true" />
</feature>
```

2) Declare your splash screens images in **config.xml** ,which you have already done.

I suggest you to keep images in default density folders of android project (ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi etc) instead of screen/android folder as it will simplifiy your project structure.

```
    <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
    <splash
        density="land-hdpi"
        src="res/drawable-land-hdpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="land-ldpi"
        src="res/drawable-land-ldpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="land-mdpi"
        src="res/drawable-land-mdpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="land-xhdpi"
        src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="port-hdpi"
        src="res/drawable-hdpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="port-ldpi"
        src="res/drawable-ldpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="port-mdpi"
        src="res/drawable-mdpi/splash.png" />
    <splash
        density="port-xhdpi"
        src="res/drawable-xhdpi/splash.png" />
</platform>
```

3)  Add [Splash screen plugin class](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/src/android/SplashScreen.java) into your android project structure under **org.apache.cordova.splashscreen** package or install  splash screen Cordova plugin

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova/splashscreen/splashscreen.html

4) Final and most important step you must have cordova.js in your www folder

[image: Cordova.js in assets]

And after that I was able to run your web app

[image]

I am android developer I guess something similar you might need to do for iOS

Answer (score 2):

The only fix that worked for me was found here:
http://www.codingandclimbing.co.uk/blog/ionic-2-fix-splash-screen-white-screen-issue-14

basically edit your config.xml file. The splashscreen setup should look like this:

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen"/>
</feature>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i put an ALERT before first screen still mounted.

Comment: wish I could upvote this more.  While debugging, I have an alert display as early as possible, so I can attach my debugger.  on IOS, the alert shows above the blank screen.  on android (as of v11) I'm guessing it's behind the white screen displayed...

Comment: are you saying that the (early) alert causes the app to white screen

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem while using cordova with ember.js. It was about the url change strategy of my application.

Have a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339647/phonegap-build-ios-app-has-blank-white-screen-after-splash-screen/20407634#20407634), it maybe related with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should install the `splash-screen` plugin for both iOS and Android to work properly if you are adding splash in `config.xml`. or else without `splash-screen` plugin what you could try to do is making an splash screen with HTML, divide your body in 2 parts: content and login. Then you set the content style display: none. When the app is done loading you just set loading screen display: none and content screen display: block or whatever you want

And you missing below preferences in your `config.xml`

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true|false" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true|false" />
```

Comment: The `Splash Screen` plugins is not needful to install without that we can also display splash screen just for your information.

Comment: Can you tell me how we can do without Splash-screen plugin it would be very helpful. @jaydroider

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this preference to your config.xml, maybe this is the problem

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

A missing `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy">` tag on the `head` caused a white-screen in my case.

Comment: Yuval A. what would be the reason adding this would fix your issue?

Comment: @mediaguru it probably blocked some resources without it... (I did not give an example for a full Content-Security-Policy tag)

Comment: Ok thanks.  I currently have that line commented out in my index.html.  Perhaps I'll uncomment and see what happens.  My problem is slightly different. After the splash screen screen goes blank.  If I rotate the device, the view appears but no interface items work. Rotate back and all functions work.

Answer (score 1):

I added these lines in config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="6000" />
```

I also have a black screen when I give screendelay as 3000.so I changed to 6000.I think cordova take some time to load your js,css and image files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally commented the state definition in app.js.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with ES6, it runs perfectly on iPhone and Android 6, but it doesn't work with Android 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

I have this situation and solved it.

In my case it was something similar to this code:

```
$scope.images.push({ id: i, src: "http://placehold.it/50x50" , pstb, trno});
```

The above code run well on android 7.0 but only white screen after splash on android 4.4.4

Changed to this:

```
$scope.images.push({ id: i, src: "http://placehold.it/50x50", pstb: pstb, trno: trno});
```

Run on all devices (at least all my devices)

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I'll add it to the list of potential experiments here - I never worked out how this was happening, but it was resolved by deleting the entire `platforms` folder and `node_modules`, then re-adding the platform.

Answer (score -1):

1>> If you suspect there's an exception being thrown during startup, you can use the browser platform to track it down.
2>>Pin your plugins to a specific version using the spec parameter in the config.xml. This will save you some heartache in the future.