# Xcode8.1 and Safari 10.0.1 not showing debug or console errors?

Tags: ios, cordova, safari, ios-simulator, xcode8

Arrgghh....I am so fed up with Apple.  I have none of the problems with Android that I continually have with Apple.

Went to go load my app onto a local device (iPhone 6s) that had iOS 10.1 on it.  Xcode wouldn't play with that so I had to upgrade to Xcode 8.1 and everything broke.  I am now just trying to deploy my project to the simulator, it builds fine and deploys - I see my splash screen and then the app goes blank.  Zero errors are displayed in the console yet I am not able to see the app in Safari Develop "Simulator" (not even there).

```
Mac 10.11.6 El Capitan
Xcode 8.1 (8B62)
Cordova 6.4.0
Project platform iOS: 4.2.1 (I even upgraded it to 4.3.0 but still nothing, then rebuilt project with 4.2.1 again)

Project iOS Target: 9.3
Deployment Target: 9.3 (iPhone only)

Simulators: 10.0, 10.1, 9.3
```

It was deploying just fine to Simulator iPhone 6x with Xcode 8.0 for 9.3 deployments, but upgrading to Xcode 8.1 broke it.  I am going to remove the Simulators 10.0/10.1.  the biggest issue is it builds just fine but deploys splash screen then goes blank.

Comment: I've noticed that I've needed to restart Safari AFTER launching from Xcode lately -- and only then does the simulator show up in the Develop menu. I'm on Sierra / Xcode 8.1.

Comment: I thought I had already done that but apparently I had not.  I am now able to see Safari Develop "Simulator" as my app loads.  However, it is not providing any other help in understanding why I can see my app.  It too is indicating no errors or issues within console and shows me a blank app.

I do see though that there is almost NO html files loaded...just a few ionic components and then empty HTML tags.  I can't imagine it gets that far, without any of my JS or templates, without registering some errors.  Again though, same code on Android and everything comes up clean.

Comment: Have you tried hitting reload (cmd-R) in the debugger? I ran into one of those startup exceptions a while back (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554165/cordova-white-screen-after-splash-no-exceptions-in-console) - hitting reload did cause the exception to show up finally.

Comment: cmd-R in Safari or in Xcode ?

Comment: i tried that cmd-R in Safari and waa-laa...the error finally pop'd up.  i re-compiled the app like 5 times...and each time it wouldn't register any errors in Xcode or in Safari - only until i hit cmd-R in Safari after it loaded would finally the error appear.  not certain how you discovered this but i am certain i never would have.  apple $hit is so damn buggy and consistently unreliable on a regular basis.  Thx!

Comment: Glad to help. The platform-specific gotchas are really annoying -- my list of "things to look at" seems to grow from week to week.

Answer (score 2):

Relaunch Safari after Simulator starts running.

Answer (score 1):

@eb1 gets credit for these 'fixes'.

After upgrading to Xcode 8.1 as well as Safari 10.0.1 I was no longer able to see compile, debug or JS errors in either the Xcode console or the Safari Develop Simulator debug/console sections.

After compiling my project, the simulator would show my app splash screen and then go blank.  no errors, messages, console output - nothing.  In addition, Safari was no longer displaying the "Develop -> Simulator" option to debug my app.

1. To fix this, I had to shut down Xcode and Safari, and in this order, relaunch Xcode, load the project into Xcode and then start Safari - only then would the Develop->Simulator dropdown show up.
2. But even after getting #1 to show up, I still wasn't able to see any bugs, or code issues within the Develop->Simulator window after the app had loaded.  After it was loaded it would just be blank and i couldn't see what any issues that was causing my app to not be working.  Well, after it was loaded i had to press "cmd-R" to reload the console/debug messages and then i was able to see the issues breaking my app.  I have to do this every time now...load the app, see nothing, then cmd-R...then able to see the bugs/breaks.
3. I still don't have a solution for doing the same within Xcode console - prior to upgrading I could see almost all of the same issues in both Xcode and Safari, but now only in Safari (using solution #2 above).  Xcode shows everything loaded fine, while Safari cmd-R 'after' loading is now showing the compile issues.

If anyone ever finds a solution for #3, please please add to this thread.