# App shows blank white screen in iOS 8.1

Tags: cordova, ionic2

When I run the application on iPhone with iOS version 8.1, The splash screen shows up and then shows a blank white screen, However it works perfectly in iOS 9 and in iOS 10 but not in iOS 8.

I'm using **wkWebView** for iOS and **crosswalk** for android.

**My ionic version:**

> Cordova: 6.4.0
>   Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
>   Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
>   Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
>   Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.31
>   Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.17
>   ios-deploy version: Not installed
>   ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
>   OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
>   Node Version: v4.4.5
>   Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62

I have attached the logs generated by xcode when the app is launched.

> 2016-11-17 14:31:58.599 MyApp[20570:1836900] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
>   2016-11-17 14:32:03.796 MyApp[20570:1836900] Using UIWebView
>   2016-11-17 14:32:03.804 MyApp[20570:1836900] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.040054ms
>   2016-11-17 14:32:03.819 MyApp[20570:1836900] Unlimited access to network resources
>   2016-11-17 14:32:03.819 MyApp[20570:1836900] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 14.876008ms
>   2016-11-17 14:32:03.820 MyApp[20570:1836900] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.169992ms
>   2016-11-17 14:32:03.967 MyApp[20570:1836900] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 146.840990ms
>   2016-11-17 14:32:03.972 MyApp[20570:1836900] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 5.607009ms
>   2016-11-17 14:32:03.973 MyApp[20570:1836900] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.159979ms
>   2016-11-17 14:32:03.973 MyApp[20570:1836900] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 169.110000ms
>   2016-11-17 14:32:05.253 MyApp[20570:1836900] Resetting plugins due to page load.
>   2016-11-17 14:32:08.762 MyApp[20570:1836900] Finished load of: file:///Users/3esoftwaresolutions/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3D72C95F-BD7C-4387-A85B-C751EC4F38B9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/916CDBC4-4D44-4D27-8BFF-3DA9E8A0642B/My%20App.app/www/index.html
>   2016-11-17 14:32:08.833 MyApp[20570:1836900] THREAD WARNING: ['Device'] took '30.730957' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
>   2016-11-17 14:32:08.977 MyApp[20570:1836900] DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER 544 ms

I don't get any error on the Xcode console as well.

My **config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="in.app.my" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>My App</name>
    <description>An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.3" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="19+" />
    <preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
    <preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
    <preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="true" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git" />
</widget>
```

My question is: How to debug this issue? Does ionic2 supports iOS8 and iOS8.1? How to make the app compatible with 8 and 8.1?

Comment: To see startup exceptions in the Safari developer tools debugger, you need to reload the page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554165/cordova-white-screen-after-splash-no-exceptions-in-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic 2 support ios 8, 8.1 . Should you run your app on emulator ios 8 and view log on safari ? It help you detect your problem.
  Reference [this link](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787) to know view log on safari.

Cheer!

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot. I'm now able to debug using safari web inspector