# Getting white-screen on emulator using cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-cordova

I have developed a web application in angular.I want to convert it into android application.

Whenever I run the command "cordova run browser" it is working fine but as soon as I run the command "cordova run android" it open up the emulator complied successfully but getting white blank screen.

I have changed target as es5 in tsconfig file but nothing get happens well.

I don't know where I am getting wrong.Kindly help to solve the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately the "white screen" error condition is pretty generic. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554165/cordova-white-screen-after-splash-no-exceptions-in-console

The best thing that I've found is to open up Chrome dev tools and connect to the Android emulator, and then hit refresh to get the actual error the app is running into at startup. That helps to isolate where the problem is coming from. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Not every plugin and code work correctly in phone, or in web.

Excample my plugins worked very good, but in ios i dont saw nothing.

First try build
cordova build android

And my tipp is use ionic, like
ionic cordova run android
and try like this
ionic cordova run android --no-native-run

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I have added ionic to existing angular project. and run the command "ionic serve" but I am getting below error.> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[ng] An unhandled exception occurred: Project "app" does not exist.
[ng] See "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-2IGpvv\angular-errors.log" for further details.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127).        
        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error
        details.